# Specify constraints during table creation by select into

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can we explicitly specify "not null" and "primary key" constraints for a column of table that is dynamically created through execution of "select into"? Something like this:

```
SELECT cast(seqNo as int) as Id [PK, NOT NULL] into newTable from existingTable
```

The ability to specify any of constraints demonstrated between brackets above such as [PK, NOT NULl] is desired

Answer (score 2):

There's no devoted syntax for this, as mentioned in [the docs on the `INTO` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-and-restrictions):

> Indexes, constraints, and triggers defined in the source table are not transferred to the new table, nor can they be specified in the `SELECT...INTO` statement. If these objects are required, you can create them after executing the `SELECT...INTO` statement.

...But depending on what kind of constraint you want to implement, it is possible implicitly.

For example, a `NOT NULL` constraint can be indirectly defined by using the `ISNULL()` function wrapped around the column like so:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(cast(seqNo as int), 0) as Id
into newTable 
from existingTable
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT.. INTO uses the leading rows from the execution plan to generate the spec of the new table.

To do what you want you will need 3 steps

1. define a table variable with
2. select into a new table, wrapping the table variable first and then union back your table and make sure sql understand that there is no change of having null in the results with both ISNULL(id,0) and WHERE id is not null
3. alter the table to add the primary key.

here is a sample of what the your query would look like:

```
    DECLARE @TEMPLATE TABLE
                        ( Id INT NOT NULL
                        , col2 VARCHAR(200)
                        )
        
    SELECT Id, StockCode
    INTO newTable
    FROM    (SELECT Id, col2
               FROM @TEMPLATE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ISNULL(CAST( Id as INT),0) as Id
                , col2
             FROM existingTable
             WHERE Id IS NOT NULL
            ) DRV
    
    ALTER TABLE newTable
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    ;
```